# What module is missing when I try to import skimage? Python 3.5

Tags: python

When I run the line from skimage import io I get the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Dilshad\Desktop\project_7-8-2015\8_bands\Program_camera.py", line 16, in <module>
from Functions_8bands import *
File "C:\Users\Dilshad\Desktop\project_7-8-2015\8_bands\Functions_8bands.py", line 5, in <module>
from skimage import io
File "C:\Users\Dilshad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\skimage\io\__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
from ._io import *
File "C:\Users\Dilshad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\skimage\io\_io.py", line 8, in <module>
from ..color import rgb2grey
File "C:\Users\Dilshad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\skimage\color\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
from .colorconv import (convert_colorspace,
File "C:\Users\Dilshad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\skimage\color\colorconv.py", line 58, in <module>
from scipy import linalg
File "C:\Users\Dilshad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\scipy\linalg\__init__.py", line 172, in <module>
from .misc import *
File "C:\Users\Dilshad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\scipy\linalg\misc.py", line 5, in <module>
from .blas import get_blas_funcs
File "C:\Users\Dilshad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\scipy\linalg\blas.py", line 155, in <module>
from scipy.linalg import _fblas
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

I've searched through the site-package file and I see that io exists so I'm not really sure whats's missing.

Comment: How about `from scipy.linalg import _fblas` from the bottom of the traceback?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why it worked but installing numpy +mkl instead of numpy vanilla from the unofficial binary site on UCI got around this for me.